# Laravel error en ejecutar migración para actualizar campo con ForeignKey

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, migration

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 7, cree una migración para agregar un campo que contiene una relación foranea, pero me arroja un error al intentar ejecutarla con migrate:roolback

Código de la Migración

```
class AddPositionToCandidate extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('candidates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('position_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('position_id')->references('id')->on('positions');
        
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('candidates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['position_id']);
            $table->dropColumn('position_id');
        });
           
    }
}
```

El error que arroja al ejecutarla con

```
php artisan migrate:roolback


SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'candidates_position_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `candidates` drop foreign key `candidates_position_id_foreign`)
```

Aclaro que en la tabla no existe ni el campo ni la relación

Comment: ¿Nos muestras el orden en el que se ejecutan las migraciones?

Comment: Esta es la ultima, igual probé muchas formas, leí la documentación de Laravel 7 y no pude hacerlo, opte (mala práctica) como aún esta en desarrollo modificar las relaciones anteriores. No se como cerrar la pregunta, alguién puede decirme ?